# Raid1 in Bios but only see one partition in Disks

Tags: ubuntu, raid

My PC has 2 Disks, each one is 256GB. I set up RAID 1 in BIOS and installed Ubuntu.
When I check the Disks program from Ubuntu, I see overall 3 disks. Number 1 and 2 are the physical disks and they are descried as RAID members.
When I check the 3rd Disk, I only see 2 partitions in the volumes. I don't understand why? I thought I'm supposed to see 3 partitions. Was the RAID 1 failed? [image]

This is the relevant output from `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238,49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SQF-S25Z4-256GDS
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3C7252BB-4DF9-54DB-8B0D-6E4A11247494

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 500113407 499062784  238G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdb: 238,49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SQF-S25Z4-256GDS
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3C7252BB-4DF9-54DB-8B0D-6E4A11247494

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 500113407 499062784  238G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/isw_beij: 238,48 GiB, 256058200064 bytes, 500113672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3C7252BB-4DF9-54DB-8B0D-6E4A11247494

Device                                  Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mapper/isw_beij1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/mapper/isw_beij2 1050624 500113407 499062784  238G Linux filesystem
```

Here is the output from `sudo parted /dev/mapper/isw_beij --algin optimal unit MiB print`:

```
Model: Linux device-mapper (mirror) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/isw_beij: 244196MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start    End        Size       File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1,00MiB  513MiB     512MiB     fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      513MiB   244196MiB  243683MiB  ext4
```

What I expect to see in the disk is actually a third partition like this picture. This was another PC (different BIOS Version, but with the same RAID 1 setting as the PC from the first picture)[image]

Comment: The "3rd disk" you have highlighted in the screenshot appears to have a ~540MB EFI boot parition and a 256GB ext4 partition.  What is the "third partition" you expected to find?  (If you answer, please edit your question and put the answer there, not in a comment)

Comment: Did you actually make three partitions on your raid volume?  It looks like you only made two, an EFI boot partition and an ext4 partition for linux.

Comment: BTW, unless you need to dual boot with windows, you're probably better off using [mdadm](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Linux_Raid) software raid than BIOS fakeraid.  Linux's software raid is generally better than any fakeraid implementation (which is just software raid in an eprom, not hardware raid), and better than most actual hardware raid cards.  Also, both fakeraid and hardware raid tend to be vendor-specific, which means that if you ever need to replace the motherboard (or the HW raid card) you will have to replace it with the same brand, if not the exact same model.

Comment: Hello @cas, I had only selected the two physical disks in the BIOS and then created the RAID volume. I had never create any EFI boot partition and ext4 partition. Therefore I don't really understand where do all these partitions come from.

A dual boot is not wished for the PC. The PC only needs one Linux system.I have never seen a hardware raid cards. Seems like I've been using the BIOS fakeraid all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your other PC uses the old MBR partitioning scheme, where there can be a maximum of 4 primary partitions, and one of these can be an *extended partition* which can act as a container for further partitions (sometimes called *logical partitions*). That makes primary partitions a very scarce resource, and some OSs require a primary partition for booting, unless a third-party boot manager (e.g. GRUB) is used.

The extended partition's only role is to act as a container for any and all non-primary partitions: it is not useful by itself.

As a result, some people and OS installers have adopted a practice of creating at most one regular primary partition (to allow the disk be "bootable") and creating any further partitions within an extended partition "container". This leaves two primary partition slots free against any possible future need. This is also how MS-DOS originally used the MBR partitioning by necessity, as the MS-DOS version of `fdisk` only allowed a maximum of one primary FAT partition per disk, but creation of logical partitions within an extended partition was not restricted.

So, the three-partition layout actually has only two partitions that can hold filesystems: the primary partition #1 and the logical partition #5.

(When using MBR, Linux reserves partition number slots 1-4 for primary/extended partitions, and logical disks are assigned partition numbers starting from 5.)

---

On the other hand, the PC you are asking about uses a more modern GPT partitioning scheme, where all partitions are equal and no "containers" such as extended partitions are needed nor even possible.

Your MBR-partitioned system has two usable partitions, same as the GPT-partitioned one. The fact that there is a partition named "EFI System Partition" indicates the GPT-partitioned system is using UEFI firmware rather than legacy BIOS. For UEFI, the EFI System Partition is *mandatory*, as it is the place where UEFI bootloader must be placed.

Unlike legacy BIOS, UEFI can *read files* and so UEFI bootloader is a regular file, instead of a raw block of binary code at a specific disk location like BIOS's Master Boot Record or a Partition Boot Record.

It looks like the other PC may be also set up to boot UEFI-style, but for whatever reason, it has been partitioned using legacy MBR partitioning. That will limit the maximum size of the disk to just under 2 TB, as that's the maximum size the MBR will handle.

If you needed more than 2 TB of disk space on a single disk, you could just clone the system disk of your GPT-partitioned system to a disk bigger than 2 TB and then expand the Linux partition to use the rest of the disk. (It's not necessarily the best idea... but with GPT, it is *possible*.)

Answer (score 0):

The third disk `/dev/mapper/isw_beij` looks very much like it's the composite RAID1 device.

You also have direct access to the two halves of the mirror as `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` - but you should not touch these at all. Ever.

The RAID1 device is formatted as GPT, but it appears that the graphical utility is trying to interpret the protective MBR partition table, which was created to help protect the disk partition table from being modified by utilities that do not recognise GPT.

You can use `parted` (as root) to display the true partition table for GPT:

```
parted /dev/mapper/isw_beij --align optimal unit MiB print
```

Unlike MBR, GPT doesn't use extended partitions, so you won't find one in the table. Instead the full device (all but the EFI partition) is assigned as a Linux partition, nominally with an `ext4` filesystem.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov oops, yes, thank you. I was testing locally and forgot to fix up the device name!

Comment: Hello @roaima, thank you for your answer. I attached the output from ```parted``` in my original post.
I think this matches what the Disks GUI shows.

Comment: @WJPING I don't see the problem. You don't need an extended partition so there isn't one. Instead you've got just the full device assigned as a Linux (`ext4`) partition